# Datetime independente

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para geração de senha "*time on based TOTP*", mas estou tendo dificuldade quando o fuso horário do celular está desativado ou o usuário modifica a data/hora.

Já pensei em fazer o sincronismo da data com NTP para o SystemClock, mas quando o aparelho é reiniciado a data volta para a hora alterada.

É possível criar um relógio independente?

Comment: Esse token vai ser utilizado somente online? Porque não buscar a data via API? Ou consultar em algum website em tempo real?

Comment: Por o usuário não pode depender de internet! :/